# What is the appropriate way to add firebase auth to firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am building an app and would like to keep authentication server side using firebase functions. I have initialized the app and added all the dependencies,

1. Express
2. Firebase
3. Firebase-admin

I get an error "firebase.auth is not a function" when I run the auth:

```
firebase.auth()
.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password)
```

I initialize my app like so:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    ...
  };
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

I have tried a ton of import options including

```
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
require('firebase/auth')
```

which gives me same error,

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

Which tells me I cant import outside of a module.

I have tried deleting the node modules and reinstalling, installing in order of firebase then firebase-admin. I have tried all solutions I can find and noting works.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase's default providers are made to be called directly from client-side code, and not from within Cloud Functions.

If you want to control the authentication process with your own server-side code, you'll have to have the verification of the credentials yourself, and then [mint a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) for the user.

Also see some of these top [search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+authentication+sign+in+user+in+cloud+functions).

Comment: What I am really stuck on is importing firebase and initializing it so that I can access auth. I have to do require('firebase/app') for it to work when I add require for auth, I dont get access to auth functions . That is where I really really need help

Comment: In Cloud Functions, you'll use the Admin SDK - which give you administrative access to the project.

Comment: Hey David. Any update here?

Comment: I tried using the admin SDK but still got the same error. Had to resort to doing authentication client side .